# Abnormal behaviour with push notifications in iOS after device goes online

Tags: ios, parse-platform, apple-push-notifications, ionic-framework

I'm using Parse for push notifications within an Ionic application. Although push notifications work correctly in both iOS and Android when the device is online, when the device goes offline and then online the behaviour in Android and iOS differ significantly.

In Android all notifications sent while the device was offline are received. In iOS either one of the following happens:

- I get all push notifications
- I get no push notifications
- I get one random push notification from the queue
- I get the last notification from the queue

Is this seemingly random behaviour expected in APNS or is there some setting I'm missing from Parse? I have read also that APNS should not be relied upon for this kind of situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From the official APNS documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/APNSOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH8-SW5):

> Apple Push Notification service includes a Quality of Service (QoS)
>   component that performs a store-and-forward function.
>
> If APNs attempts to deliver a notification and the destination device
>   is offline, APNs stores the notification for a limited period of time
>   and delivers it when the device becomes available again.
>
> **This component stores only the most recent notification per device
>   and per app. If a device is offline, sending a notification request
>   targeting that device causes the previous request to be discarded. If
>   a device remains offline for a long time, all its stored notifications
>   in APNs are discarded.**
>
> Apple Push Notification service includes a Quality of Service (QoS)
>   component that performs a store-and-forward function. If APNs attempts
>   to deliver a notification and the destination device is offline, APNs
>   stores the notification for a limited period of time and delivers it
>   when the device becomes available again. This component stores only
>   the most recent notification per device and per app. If a device is
>   offline, sending a notification request targeting that device causes
>   the previous request to be discarded. If a device remains offline for
>   a long time, all its stored notifications in APNs are discarded.

For GCM you can achieve a similar behaviour using [collapse keys](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server-ref#send-downstream):

> This parameter identifies a group of messages (e.g., with
>   collapse_key: "Updates Available") that can be collapsed, **so that only
>   the last message gets sent when delivery can be resumed.** This is
>   intended to avoid sending too many of the same messages when the
>   device comes back online or becomes active (see delay_while_idle).
>
> **Note that there is no guarantee of the order in which messages get
>   sent.**

The random behaviour on iOS seems weird, but maybe it's just because push notifications are not 100% guaranteed to be delivered, and also not in the order they were sent.

Comment: What a shame to know this, I also guess that the random behaviour is because the push notifications are called with the developer profile, I'll test it with the distribution one and see the results.